# Partial fraction of a function with two variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-fractions, maple

I am trying to decompose a function within an optimization problem. I see that Maple
and similar software products can do it for a single variable function but not
for multi-variate ones. Now, I am struggling with decomposing the following
function with only two variables $x$ and $y$:

$$f\left(x,y\right)=\frac{r_c\tau_c\lambda_cx^2 + r_n\tau_n\lambda_n y^2 + \left(r_n\tau_n\lambda_c + r_c\tau_c\lambda_n\right)xy}{r_c x + r_n x + c}$$

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: What exactly are you hoping your denominators to look like after the partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: I would like to split the function into some fractions with the same denominator. But the numerators should be free of x and y "or" they are a linear function of x and y (not having terms like x*y, x^2, or y^2. Thank you, Bernard!